# Save contacts automatically in my contact list

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to save mobile Number automatically. If I get the message from Unknown Number then I want, **that number saved automatically in my contact list with the help of flutter App**.
Now I want help for this. Because I don't know the plugin which do this. So I want Help to you people.
Regards: Munaim

Answer (score 0):

You must try to do a research before asking

googling "Flutter save contact" would have solved your question.

The library

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contact

:)